# Installing framed sliding shower doors

Tags: shower, tile

Just wrapping up my porcelain tile install on my 32x60 shower. I am installing framed sliding shower doors and was researching ahead for that. There are 3 screws installed in each vertical side. The screws provided are 1/8"x1 1/2". The instructions say to use the anchors provided, however when framing out for my shower, I installed studs right where these are going to go. What's the best way to go about doing this and are these screws sufficient? Obviously I won't be anchoring with the studs. 1 1/2" will barely make it through the track, tile, and Hardiebacker. I'm assuming these are meant to be used due to the anchors, so I should look for something longer? Also, I suppose I should predrill 3/8" holes through the ceramic with a diamond bit, huh?

Comment: One caution.  If you opt to use longer screws and anchor into the stud,   Do not over tighten and risk pulling through the track or cracking a tile.  There is no need for especially strong connections in this application.

Answer (score 1):

What you were provided with is the standard install hardware for shower doors. Most people don't know exactly where the studs are. You can definitely install the doors as recommended using the provided screws and anchors. Since you know where the studs are, you can use the longer screws but do not drill 3/8" holes, way too big. stick with the diameter of the screws provided, you don't want to have to drill the tracks with larger holes

Comment: The anchors provided are pop toggle anchors and certainly won't work in my setup.

Comment: Also, I mistyped. I meant 3/16", not 3/8". Thanks!

Comment: @EGrant23  Mistyping is OK... Misdrilling is not .. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The weight of the doors is on the tub, and it's hard to find studs behind tile.  That's why studs are not normally used for shower doors.  However, since you know where the studs are, the benefit of using longer screws is that you can get away with drilling much smaller holes.  Go for it.  Drill just barely large enough for your screw through the tile and board, and then switch to a smaller pilot drill for the joist.    Use screws that won't rust with heads that will not rip through the door frame.

Comment: Heck, once you're through the tile & backer, there's really no need to predrill the stud. It's not like he's using lag bolts to hold this up...

Comment: I would want to minimize the risk of breaking a screw because a broken screw inside the confines of the door frame would be a huge, huge PIA.

Answer (score 0):

You will be fine with the 1 1/2" screws. If you think about your install it's exactly what the manufacturer expects (99% of shower doors are tile over hardiebacker). That said if you are bothered there will be no harm in using longer screws with the same diameter.